# How to prototype with Jennic JN5148/001M00T Modules

Tags: zigbee, jennic

I am fascinated by [these](http://www.jennic.com/files/support_files/JN-DS-JN5148MO-1v4.pdf) all in one microcontrollers/zigbee radios from Jennic.  They seem to have done a much better job opening up their platform tools than say Microchip for example.  The SDK and API stacks are all freely available.  You can get a module pretty cheap too, less that [$15](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/JN5148/001M00T,534/616-1045-6-ND/2139688).  Now comes the rub:  I can't seem to find any modestly priced solution for getting started with development.  To actually use the module you need some sort of carrier board that would have a USB/JTAG interface, a crystal, and a power source.  All these things are accomplished with what Jennic calls a "[carrier board](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.jennic.com/files/support_documentation/JN-RM-2063-Carrier-and-Expansion-Boards.pdf&ei=kTAuUpTcCIbI9QTi-YHQCA&usg=AFQjCNGlG1vKl8GsewW4ram083coIyCYRQ&sig2=UkAv9e9Hu0RP7l1hokKjaw&bvm=bv.51773540,d.eWU)" which they freely provide the schematic and gerber files for.  Sadly, it seems there is no way to actually buy this board.  The only way I can find to obtain it is by buying their [$1300 evaluation kit](http://www.nxp.com/demoboard/JN516X-EK001.html).  I'm sure it is really nice, but I don't really want all that stuff.

I could just take their gerbers and have the board made for a couple hundred bucks, but I feel like I must be missing some simple solution.  Why would a company that seems to have gone out of their way to make development simple make this one part so hard?  Is there a better/cheaper way to program these devices?

Comment: Why would you need the full carrier board for it? A breakout should cost you less than $50.

Comment: Usually, I'd prefer not to have to design and layout a board just to test out a new chip.  It wouldn't just be breakout, I'd have to at least figure out how the JTAG chain works and put down a crystal and usb interface.  Or are you suggesting there is a breakout board available for purchase?

Comment: The device looks like it can be programmed via SPI or UART, and you can use an oscillator instead of a crystal. A FTDI module can add USB.

Comment: I surely could go that way, but it will still work out about the same as just having their board made (I believe).  $33 a board is what I normally pay for a 2 layer board with min quantity 4.  By the time you pay for shipping and the parts + shipping you'll be in around $200.  FTDI module is around $5 by itself.  Plus I wouldn't think that is typical use case...I mean I could do it, just wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: If you are willing to wait 10 days or so you could get a set of 3 custom breakout boards from OSH park for $10-15 total.  Or you could make one yourself with a laser printer and an iron in an hour or two...  Or do both: the fabbed board for long term use, and the in house substitute so you have a temporary platform for software work in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, the situation has changed a little: as Jennic is now fully absorbed by NXP, which also acquired Freescale, there are a couple more options to choose between.

Sticking with the JN516x family, you can now find some pluggable modules with header pins, such as:

- [DORJI JN516X JN5168 Zigbee module DZM5168M](http://www.dorji.com/products-detail.php?ProId=46)
- [MeshBee](https://www.robot-italy.com/en/mesh-bee-open-source-zigbee-pro-module-with-mcu-jn5168.html)

As an alternative, there is the formerly Freescale Kinetis KW21Z with an ARM Cortex M0+ and an 802.15.4 transceiver with an official development kit (FRDM-KW41Z) made of two boards, for just above 100$. Honestly I couldn't find anything any cheaper than that in a quick search on the web.